# Is there a non-regional German expression for the Swabian term "Gschmäckle"?

Tags: expression, german-to-english, regional

Is this term only well-known in Southern Germany or also in the deep North? Is there short alternatives for modern High German? Does anyone know a similar English *short* expression?

Comment: For the record: Never heard this in the deep North.

Comment: In the `hohen Norden` or `hoch im Norden`.

Comment: Here in Franconia, everyone will understand this, but you don't hear it very often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term isn't even well-known in all of southern Germany - a Bavarian, for example, might well not know it. According to Wikipedia:

*Der Begriff wird insbesondere für einen Beigeschmack von Speisen und Getränken oder einen verdorbenen Geruch verwendet und im übertragenen Sinn für Sonderbarkeit, spezifische, anderen auffallende und widerwärtige oder lächerliche Art eines Individuums oder Standes benutzt.*

The term seems to carry a connotation of an unpleasant or weird taste. I'm not aware of any single high German term with the exact same connotations. "Beigeschmack" probably comes closest, but isn't used in quite exactly the same way. In some cases, you can also use "anrüchig".

(Edited to add some suggestions, thanks, commenters!)

Comment: Ich würde `Beigeschmack` noch etwas hervorheben - das wird doch genau so benutzt.

Comment: **Very** rarely, in literary language or on high literary levels, the french `hautgout` is used.

Comment: I think "anrüchig" actually hits it pretty well.

Comment: @Katharina: I knew there is something more nosy than 'Beigeschmack', it was laying on my tongue! :)

Comment: @tohuwabohu: I would use 'hautgout' more often, if I knew how to write it. :)

Comment: +1 for the cool word "hautgout"

Answer (score 17):

Actually the [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gschm%C3%A4ckle) uses "anrüchig" as an expression for "Gschmäckle" for High German, which is what I have heard it as as well. The word "Beigeschmack" as mentioned in an earlier comment works too, but I think "anrüchig" nails it.

[Leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&p=Ci4HO3kMAA&search=dingy&trestr=0x8004) suggests to translate "anrüchig" with "dingy".

Comment: Ich finde 'Beigeschmack' etwas schwächer, weil es Platz für einen Hauptgeschmack läßt, der bei 'anrüchig' nicht so präsent ist.

Comment: I absolutely agree with that.

Answer (score 8):

In High German you could say

> Die Sache stinkt. / Das ist oberfaul.

for the figuratively used *Gschmäckle*.

In English

> It's fishy / not quite kosher.

Comment: "nicht ganz koscher" gibt's auch im Deutschen :)

Comment: @OregonGhost stimmt!

Comment: "Das ist oberfaul." is a lot stronger than "Das hat ein Gschmäckle.".

Comment: While I'm not coming from the south and know the German term more in passing (I sure haven't ever used it myself, for example), I think 'fishy' is a pretty good English equivalent. That's exactly how I use 'fishy' in English. At least for those meanings of 'Gschmäckle' which aren't explicitly referring to food.

Comment: Are you sure "oberfaul" is standard German (Hochdeutsch)? It seems closer to youth language to me.

Answer (score 7):

Actually "Gschmäckle" is being used and understood across Germany in its metaphorical use. There, it describes something about a person's actions that might possibly be regarded as inappropriate, especially in political or economical contexts.

E.g. Shortly after Chancellor Schröder was voted out of office, he took on a highly-paid position with the Russian state-owned oil and gas company "Gazprom". Previously (as Chancellor), Schröder had brought about a deal between Germany and Russia concerning the building of a new gas pipeline.

So, people said that Schröder's move to Gazprom had a 'Gschmäckle'.

In that context, "Beigeschmack" is a close alternative in High German.

Comment: @autistic: Why are you posting this here, and not on the original SO thread? Anyhow, of course valgrind will report a leak. In practise, on any modern OS, the OS will release all memory of a program once it terminates. I'm not saying one should leave "normal" cleanup to the OS, but in cases where the situation of a failed realloc is handled by an immediate call to exit() I think it is quite acceptable to let the OS clean up. Things might be different in embedded systems or very old environments. But even DOS did clean up after a program exited...unless it was TSR program.

Comment: Yo can verify this by allocating a substantial amount of memory, not freeing it, pause it, then exit. In between, look at your total system's memory (linux: >free - m< or, more dynamic, use htop.)

Comment: [Your logical fallacy is anecdotal](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/anecdotal). *"Anyhow, of course valgrind will report a leak."* ... this is because there *is* a leak... in a career where you would be instructed to use this tool, do you think QA would agree or disagree with you? Perhaps on *your system*, `exit` causes memory to be reclaimed... this isn't required by the standard, though. That's the thing about C, it isn't defined by *your system*, or even *most systems*, but by ISO/IEC 9899:201x... something which I cited, which compiler devs must adhere to, which you're arguing with.

Comment: I'm done here, StackOverflow is not beginner-friendly as it once was; it became a "jobs" network which fuels anti-competitive behaviour. Feel free to flag these comments when you're done. I won't hold a grudge, as I will admit that these comments don't belong here... the problem is that I can't respond on the main site due to a ban. There are quite a few who will try to exaggerate *rudeness* of *facts* I present, I suspect their motivation is that anti-competitive stuff I referred to... now, I'm going to go and enjoy reddit, where that stupid behaviour doesn't happen so much. Peace.

Comment: On one final note, I wonder what happens if you use `realloc` like this in a shared process such as Windows services (where your process shares physical address space with other services)... *hmmmm*...

Comment: @autistic I concede that a strictly standard-adhering program should not rely on anything outside of the language. And thanks for the information on POSIX; that does seem to me to break the standard's definition of realloc, does it not?

Comment: My final note: When (at least in Linux environments) you truly run out of memory, the system will at least enter threshing, or even worse, slowing down to an absolute crawl. Just calling exit() rather than free in my experience can resolve this quickly, whereas free() might take so long that the OOMKiller might be faster and possibly shoot down a different process.

Comment: @autistic >I'm done here, StackOverflow is not beginner-friendly as it once was; it became a "jobs" network which fuels anti-competitive behaviour.<  SO never encouraged 'competitive behaviour'. >... the problem is that I can't respond on the main site due to a ban. There are quite a few who will try to exaggerate rudeness of facts I present,< Not rudeness of facts (which is impossible anyhow), but rudeness of presentation. You might want to think about that.

Comment: *Actually "Gschmäckle" is being used and understood across Germany in its metaphorical use.* I disagree. I've heard this term exactly once, a few years ago, used by a consumer adviser in radio criticizing a company's business conduct, stating "In Swabia we would say 'es hat Gschmäckle'". Before that I would have had no clue what it meant and without the explanation would have thought it hat something to do with taste (Geschmack).

Answer (score 6):

As was already stated Gschmäckle is definetely a bad aftertaste. "Beigeschmack" doesn't transport that for be. It would be "schlechter beigeschmack". Gschmäckle mustn't cover all taste. (I went to school in Stuttgart ;-))

Comment: I would suggest to use "fader Beigeschmack" instead of "schlechter Beigeschmack" here.

Answer (score -1):

Sehr hochgestochen-altmodisch-bildungssprachlich kann man sagen:

> Die Sache hat ein Odeur.

Ich fürchte bloß, dass 60 Prozent der deutschsprechenden Population den Satz dann nicht oder nur ahnungsweise verstehen.

Answer (score -3):

The non-regional term would be *Geschmack*, which could be translated as *taste* or *flavour*.

Comment: I think "Geschmack" is too neutral here, since "Gschmäckle" is supposed to express more than just taste but more like an aftertaste, in a bad way.

Comment: "Gschmäckle"  has absolutely nothing to do with taste, but rather with smell. Swabian dialect uses "schmecken" for "riechen"